# Apache Beam python, how to package using a different tool than pip?

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-dataflow, setuptools, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam pipline that gets triggered using Airflow. In my dev environment, Airflow is able to construct the package (using pip I assume) and then upload that to Dataflow to run it afterwords. However, in my production environment it's another kind of story.

This is the output of the Airflow operator that is responsible of starting the Dataflow job

---

```
*** Log file isn't local.
*** Fetching here: http://work4.podb.hello.io:8793/log/learning.pack_operation/model_predict/2018-07-17T00:00:00/2.log

[2018-07-23 21:00:07,943] {cli.py:374} INFO - Running on host work4.podb.hello.io
[2018-07-23 21:00:07,987] {models.py:1197} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: learning.pack_operation.model_predict 2018-07-17 00:00:00 [queued]>
[2018-07-23 21:00:08,004] {models.py:1197} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: learning.pack_operation.model_predict 2018-07-17 00:00:00 [queued]>
[2018-07-23 21:00:08,005] {models.py:1407} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 2 of 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2018-07-23 21:00:08,026] {models.py:1428} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): model_predict> on 2018-07-17 00:00:00
[2018-07-23 21:00:08,026] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', u'airflow run learning.pack_operation model_predict 2018-07-17T00:00:00 --job_id 725805 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/learning/pack_operation/dag.py']
[2018-07-23 21:00:09,185] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:09,184] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2018-07-23 21:00:09,205] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:09,205] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
[2018-07-23 21:00:09,944] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:09,943] {configuration.py:206} WARNING - section/key [celery/celery_ssl_active] not found in config
[2018-07-23 21:00:09,945] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:09,944] {default_celery.py:41} WARNING - Celery Executor will run without SSL
[2018-07-23 21:00:09,951] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:09,946] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2018-07-23 21:00:10,088] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:10,087] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/lib/hello-processing/processing/dags/learning/pack_operation/dag.py
[2018-07-23 21:00:12,242] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:12,242] {bash_operator.py:70} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
[2018-07-23 21:00:12,243] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:  /tmp
[2018-07-23 21:00:12,245] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:12,244] {bash_operator.py:80} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpiThdaC//tmp/airflowtmpiThdaC/model_predictiogrlD
[2018-07-23 21:00:12,246] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:12,245] {bash_operator.py:88} INFO - Running command: python /usr/lib/hello-processing/data_learning_tools/inference/model_predict/sklearn_api/predictor.py                 --input-filebase=gs://1e42-analytics_data/learning/pack_operation/20180717_1_0_0/extracted-*.json                 --output-table=hello-analytics:learning.pack_operation_inferred_1_0_020180717                 --model-path=gs://1e42-analytics_data/learning/airflow_settings/model.pkl                 --description-path=gs://1e42-analytics_data/learning/airflow_settings/description.json                 --ids=user_id,bought_pack,targeted                 --batch-size=1000                 --runner=DataflowRunner                 --job-name=model-pack-operation-20180723-210012                 --region=europe-west1                 --project=hello-analytics                 --max-num-workers=10                 --temp-location=gs://1e42-analytics_data/learning/airflow_settings/tmp                 --staging-location=gs://1e42-analytics_data/learning/airflow_settings/staging                 --library=xgboost
[2018-07-23 21:00:12,246] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:               
[2018-07-23 21:00:12,254] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:12,253] {bash_operator.py:97} INFO - Output:
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,144] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,143] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - /usr/lib/hello-processing/oauth2client/contrib/gce.py:99: UserWarning: You have requested explicit scopes to be used with a GCE service account.
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,144] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,143] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - Using this argument will have no effect on the actual scopes for tokens
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,145] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,143] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - requested. These scopes are set at VM instance creation time and
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,145] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,143] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - can't be overridden in the request.
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,145] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,143] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - 
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,145] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,143] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - warnings.warn(_SCOPES_WARNING)
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,147] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,146] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - /usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py:160: DeprecationWarning: object() takes no parameters
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,147] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,147] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - super(GcsIO, cls).__new__(cls, storage_client))
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,416] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,415] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - /usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/coders/typecoders.py:133: UserWarning: Using fallback coder for typehint: Any.
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,417] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,416] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - warnings.warn('Using fallback coder for typehint: %r.' % typehint)
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,448] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,447] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - /usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/coders/typecoders.py:133: UserWarning: Using fallback coder for typehint: Dict[Any, Any].
[2018-07-23 21:00:15,449] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:15,448] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - warnings.warn('Using fallback coder for typehint: %r.' % typehint)
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,293] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,292] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - running sdist
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,293] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,293] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - running egg_info
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,303] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,303] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - creating model_predict_sklearn.egg-info
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,305] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,305] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - writing requirements to model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/requires.txt
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,306] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,305] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - writing model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/PKG-INFO
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,307] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,307] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - writing top-level names to model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/top_level.txt
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,308] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,307] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - writing dependency_links to model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,315] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,315] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - writing manifest file 'model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,323] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,322] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - reading manifest file 'model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,324] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,324] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - writing manifest file 'model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,325] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,324] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst, README.txt
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,325] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,324] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - 
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,325] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,324] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - running check
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,419] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,417] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - warning: check: missing required meta-data: url
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,420] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,417] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - 
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,420] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,417] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - creating model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,420] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,417] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - creating model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/lib
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,420] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,417] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - creating model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/model_predict_sklearn.egg-info
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,420] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,417] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying files to model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0...
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,421] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,417] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying setup.py -> model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,421] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,418] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying lib/__init__.py -> model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/lib
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,421] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,418] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying lib/gcp.py -> model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/lib
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,421] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,418] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying lib/models.py -> model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/lib
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,422] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,418] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying lib/transforms.py -> model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/lib
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,422] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,418] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying lib/utils.py -> model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/lib
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,422] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,418] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/model_predict_sklearn.egg-info
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,422] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,418] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/model_predict_sklearn.egg-info
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,423] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,418] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/model_predict_sklearn.egg-info
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,423] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,419] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/requires.txt -> model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/model_predict_sklearn.egg-info
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,427] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,419] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - copying model_predict_sklearn.egg-info/top_level.txt -> model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/model_predict_sklearn.egg-info
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,429] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,419] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - Writing model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0/setup.cfg
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,429] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,426] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - Creating tar archive
[2018-07-23 21:00:16,430] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:16,427] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - removing 'model-predict-sklearn-1.0.0' (and everything under it)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,172] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,172] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - /usr/bin/python: No module named pip
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,178] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,175] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,179] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,175] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/data_learning_tools/inference/model_predict/sklearn_api/predictor.py", line 88, in <module>
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,179] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,175] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - main()
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,179] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,175] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/data_learning_tools/inference/model_predict/sklearn_api/predictor.py", line 79, in main
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,179] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,175] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND if is_partitioned_output else BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,180] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,176] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 349, in __exit__
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,180] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,176] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - self.run().wait_until_finish()
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,180] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,176] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 342, in run
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,180] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,176] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - return self.runner.run_pipeline(self)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,181] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,176] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 315, in run_pipeline
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,181] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,176] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - self.dataflow_client.create_job(self.job), self)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,181] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,176] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 175, in wrapper
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,181] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,176] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - return fun(*args, **kwargs)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,181] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,176] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 461, in create_job
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,182] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,177] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - self.create_job_description(job)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,182] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,177] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 491, in create_job_description
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,182] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,177] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - job.options, file_copy=self._gcs_file_copy)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,182] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,177] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/dependency.py", line 400, in stage_job_resources
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,183] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,177] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - _stage_beam_sdk_tarball(sdk_remote_location, staged_path, temp_dir)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,183] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,177] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/dependency.py", line 485, in _stage_beam_sdk_tarball
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,183] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,177] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - _dependency_file_copy(_download_pypi_sdk_package(temp_dir), staged_path)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,183] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,177] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/dependency.py", line 584, in _download_pypi_sdk_package
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,184] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,177] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - processes.check_call(cmd_args)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,184] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,178] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/apache_beam/utils/processes.py", line 44, in check_call
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,185] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,178] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - return subprocess.check_call(*args, **kwargs)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,186] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,178] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,186] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,178] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,186] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,178] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/tmpB3lvC3', 'google-cloud-dataflow==2.3.0', '--no-binary', ':all:', '--no-deps']' returned non-zero exit status 1
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,308] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,306] {bash_operator.py:105} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,346] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,347] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/airflow/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,347] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     args.func(args)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,347] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 392, in run
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,347] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     pool=args.pool,
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,348] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,348] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,348] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,348] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,348] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/hello-processing/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 109, in execute
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,348] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,349] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
```

---

This is the `setup.py` of the package I want to upload to Dataflow

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging
import setuptools
import subprocess
from distutils.command.build import build as _build
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

logger = logging.getLogger("setup")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


# Build
class build(_build):
    sub_commands = _build.sub_commands + [('CustomCommands', None)]


# Custom commands
CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [(["sudo", "apt-get", "update"], "."),
                   (["sudo", "apt-get", "install", "git", "build-essential", "libatlas-base-dev", "-y"], "."),
                   (["git", "clone", "--recursive", "https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost"], "."),
                   (["sudo", "make"], "xgboost"),
                   (["sudo", "python", "setup.py", "install"], "xgboost/python-package"),
                   (["sudo", "pip", "install", "xgboost"], ".")]


# Custom commands
class CustomCommands(setuptools.Command):

    # Initialize options
    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    # Finalize options
    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    # Run custom command
    def RunCustomCommand(self, command_list):
        logger.info('Running command: %s' % command_list[0])
        p = subprocess.Popen(command_list[0], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                             cwd=command_list[1])
        stdout_data, _ = p.communicate()
        logger.info('Command output: %s' % stdout_data)

        if p.returncode != 0:
            raise RuntimeError('Command %s failed: exit code: %s' % (command_list[0], p.returncode))

    # Run
    def run(self):
        for command in CUSTOM_COMMANDS:
            self.RunCustomCommand(command)


# Get required packages
def get_required_packages():
    return [
        'google-cloud-storage==1.3.2',
        'numpy==1.13.0',
        'pandas==0.23.0',
        'scikit-learn==0.19.1',
        # 'xgboost==0.71'. Install XGBoost from source. Install from pip doesn't work as shared library is not available
        # directly on the workers (cf https://github.com/orfeon/dataflow-sample/blob/master/python/xgboost/setup.py)
    ]


# Setup
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        name='model-predict-sklearn',
        version='1.0.0',
        maintainer="Team Data Engineers",
        maintainer_email="data.engineers@hello.fr",
        packages=find_packages(),
        install_requires=get_required_packages(),
        cmdclass={
            'build': build,
            'CustomCommands': CustomCommands,
        }
    )
```

---

Along with `predict.py` the python script that is executed by the Airflow BashOperator. The Apache Beam template is also defined in that file.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import apache_beam as beam
import json
import os
import shutil
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import BigQueryDisposition

from lib.gcp import BigQuery, GCS
from lib.transforms import BatchDoFn, PredictDoFn, UnBatchDoFn
from lib.utils import Utils


# Import libraries needed in the transforms. They are given to the workers with the option save_main_session = True
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Main
def main():
    conf = Utils.load_configuration()
    args = Utils.get_arguments(conf)

    options = args.__dict__



    # Copy to tmp
    base_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__).split(os.path.sep)[-1]
    dest_directory = os.path.join('/', 'tmp', base_directory)
    setup_file = os.path.join(dest_directory, 'setup.py')

    # Clean Tmp
    shutil.rmtree(dest_directory)

    shutil.copytree(os.path.dirname(__file__), dest_directory)
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(dest_directory, 'setup', '{}.py'.format(args.library)),
                    os.path.join(dest_directory, 'setup.py'))

    if 'DataflowRunner' == args.runner:
        # We pass all args in the pipeline options, only the relevant ones will be used!
        options['save_main_session'] = True
        options['setup_file'] = setup_file

    # Options
    pipeline_options = beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)

    model_file = GCS.get_object_as_file(options['project'], options['model_path'])
    description_file = GCS.get_object_as_file(options['project'], options['description_path'])

    ids = options['ids'].split(',')

    description = json.load(description_file)

    # Map of column name to column type to be able to cast them after reading
    fields = {field["name"]: Utils.bigquery_to_pandas_type(field["type"]) for field in description}

    table_schema = BigQuery.make_table_schema(ids)

    # https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L83
    is_partitioned_output = '$' in options['output_table']

    with beam.Pipeline(args.runner, pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        outputs = (
                pipeline
                | 'ReadFromFile' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(options['input_filebase'])
                | 'DecodeLine' >> beam.Map(Utils.decode_input(ids))
                | 'Batch' >> beam.ParDo(BatchDoFn(options['batch_size']))
                | 'Predict' >> beam.ParDo(PredictDoFn(model_file, fields))
                | 'Unbatch' >> beam.ParDo(UnBatchDoFn())
                | 'FormatOutput' >> beam.Map(Utils.format_output)
        )

        outputs | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            options['output_table'],
            schema=table_schema,
            create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER if is_partitioned_output else BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND if is_partitioned_output else BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
        )

    # Clean Tmp
    shutil.rmtree(dest_directory)


# Script
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

My questions is the following, how Can I package without using `pip` in my production environment. 
If you take a look at Airflow BashOperator logs, especially this part

```
[2018-07-23 21:00:17,186] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 21:00:17,178] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/tmpB3lvC3', 'google-cloud-dataflow==2.3.0', '--no-binary', ':all:', '--no-deps']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

maybe I can use `setuptools` ?

This is what I get in my dev environment:

```
>/usr/bin/python -m pip --version
pip 18.0 from /usr/lib/hello-processing/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

But in my prod environment, I'm getting this:

```
>/usr/bin/python -m pip --version
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
```